# Не могу понять как сделать разделение сообщения в telebot

Tags: python, telebot, sqlite3

Пользователь пишет боту `Казино 1` и бот должен указать второй аргумент(`сумму`) `1` как сумму ставки, но у меня почему то не получается делить обычное сообщение. Если оно будет указано как команда - `/casino 1`, то все будет работать и бот будет видеть второй аргумент(`сумму`) в сообщении. Как я могу решить эту проблему, может что-то не так прописываю? Работаю с [telebot](/questions/tagged/telebot) на [python](/questions/tagged/python), используя базу данных [sqlite3](/questions/tagged/sqlite3)

`Коды:`

`Вызов функции:`

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def commands(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id

    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT user_id FROM users WHERE user_id = ("%s")' % user_id)
    users = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()
    if len(users) == 0:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Обманщик..\n\nНеобходимо зарегистрироваться - /start')
    else:
        if message.text == 'Казино':
            casino(message)
```

Код написал не полностью, по этому закрытие соединения с базой данных есть, просто не указано здесь.

`Обработка сообщения:`

```py
def casino(message):
    user_id = message.chat.id

    conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db', check_same_thread=False)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT balance FROM users WHERE user_id = ("%s")' % user_id)
    users = cur.fetchall()
    conn.commit()

    for user in users:
        duration = 0
        args = message.text.split()[1]
        if args:
            try:
                duration = int(args[0])
            except ValueError:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Ошибка')
                return
            if duration > user[0]:
                bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text='Превышен баланс')
                return
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=f'{duration}')

    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Comment: потому что сообщение "Казино 1" не проходит проверку ```if message.text == "Казино"```.
вы можете использовать ```if message.text.startswith('Казино')```

Comment: @Gawain , теперь у меня почему-то указывается в ставке только первое цифра в числе, то есть при команде -  `Казино 2500` , поставится `2`

Comment: потому что вот тут ```duration = int(args[0])``` вы берете только первый символ строки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось нужно было использовать:

`message.text.startswith('Казино')` для определения иных аргументов, кроме `0 - Казино`